# Avoid unintentionally removing duplicates in list comprehension-based quicksort?

Tags: python, duplicates, list-comprehension, quicksort

I am new to Python and learning that it also implements list comprehensions, like Haskell with which I have some experience. I attempted to write a Haskell-esque `quicksort` function. **It does sort the given list, but also removes any duplicate elements**; obviously this is not a feature one generally wants in a sorting function. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? (Python 3.6)

```
def quicksort(unsorted):
    """Sorts a list least to greatest numerically using quicksort
    """
    if not unsorted:
        return []
    else:
        pivot, *rest = unsorted
        lower_sorted = quicksort([a for a in rest if a < pivot])
        upper_sorted = quicksort([a for a in rest if a > pivot])
        return lower_sorted + [pivot] + upper_sorted
```

Comment: What is `lower_rest` and `upper_rest` and the namesake pivots?

Comment: I think you are overlooking the case where `a = pivot`. You have to consider this in either `lower_sorted` or `upper_sorted`.

Comment: Assuming that the lower and upper rest and pivot are typos, consider what happens when `a` equals `pivot`.

Comment: On a side note, why not just use the `sorted()` built-in function to sort a list  numerically?

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi It's not for use in any kind of actual project or I wouldn't be re-implementing built-in functions, I was just doing it as an exercise to start getting used to Python

Comment: Ahhh okay, welcome to Python then, and happy coding!

Comment: It helps if you include data illustrating the fail case. Something like `unsorted = [1, 2, 3, 2, 0]` should do. Then by editing `print(pivot, '|', rest)` into your function, you can see where the error happens yourself (your unhandled case `a == pivot`).

Comment: You asked for other Pythonic criticisms; you handle the empty case `unsorted is None` by returning `[]` rather than `None`. If your client code always expects to get a list returned that's perfectly fine, but if you want to preserve `None` then that doesn't do that. (For example `unsorted = None` might signal that this customer-id was not found/joined in some table, and it might or might in fact be non-empty list, just it's currently not available). It's really up to you to define those sort of semantics. [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for code reviews

Comment: @smci The code doesn't work, and they're asking to fix it. Code Review is not the place for this.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: clearly I'm perfectly aware that the code doesn't work, as both my comment repeating the two-year-old solution show (handle the unhandled case `a == pivot`, already). Once OP fixes that, this is fodder for CodeReview.SE (per my main comment, and the OP's version I just edited out where they asked for other comments on the code). Again, [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for (current and future) code reviews.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the conditions (either `if a < lower_pivot` or `if a > upper_pivot`) must include an equality test.

Comment: Why is that so? If I return the lower_sorted, pivot, and upper_sorted concatenated together why do I need to include the pivot in either of them? That did correct the problem so thank you, but I guess I am struggling to understand why.

Comment: Because if you have more than one copy of `pivot`, only one of them is included.